# Setting MySQL root password in CentOS Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I installed MySQL on CentOS Linux and am trying to set the root password.  Towards this end, I took the following steps:

1. I opened the terminal and typed in `su -`  to run as root.
2. I then ran `mysql - u root`, which resulted in a lot of output and another prompt.
3. I then typed in `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NewPassHere') WHERE User='root';`

But step 3 produced the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

When I change step 3 to `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password='NewPassHere' WHERE User='root';`, I get the following error:

```
bash: UPDATE: command not found...
```

How can I resolve this error so that I can set the root password in MySQL successfully?

### Update

Based on Chuck's suggestion, I tried the following, but got the following results:

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'newpwd'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

The following two commands also had the following two results:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo service mysqld status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@localhost ~]# sudo service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

### Answer

The solution to this problem was to delete MySQL using yum remove and then to follow [the steps in this tutorial](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/31/how-to-install-mysql-server-5-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7/) explicitly.  However, I am marking Chuck's answer below as accepted because he spent so much time looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use mysqladmin to set root password.  On CENTOS 6, try:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```

This assumes you're setting the root password for a brand new install and the root password currently doesn't exist.  If you do have a root password already, you'll need to append `-p` to the end of that command and enter in the current mysql root password.

Note that this will only set the password for user root@localhost.  Once you can log into mysql, you should run a query to see how many root users actually exist.  You should probably see at least two ( root@localhost, root@127.0.0.1 ) depending on the version and platform.  You need to set the root password for each host individually.  From the mysql command line, type:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';
```

Then you can log out of mysql again and use the mysqladmin command to set all your passwords, this time with the `-h` flag to specify hosts:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password' -h127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Are you sure the mysql server is up and running?
`sudo service mysqld status` will show you if it's running and `sudo service mysqld start` should start it up if it's not

Comment: Hmm... How did you install mysql and are you sure that it IS installed?  Try `which mysql` from a terminal to make sure it is installed.  If you installed via yum, the service call should be set up automatically.  If you installed via some other method, you may need to set that up manually. `shell> cp mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql;  chmod +x /etc/init.d/mysql` should get the above command to work.  You may want to check here as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/automatic-start.html

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code to create the init.d script from mysql's website and it included the shell> prompt.  It's just a placeholder for your standard terminal prompt and doesn't mean anything.  Just start copying the command from the `cp` part.

Comment: Hmm... I'm running out of ideas here.  Is this a fresh mysql install with no data?  I'm guessing you have the mysql client installed but not the mysql server, though I'm not sure.  `sudo yum install mysql-server` will install mysql-server and set everything up but you may want to make sure you don't already have it installed.

Comment: Not without knowing how you installed it initially.  On CentOS 7, this guide looks pretty useful as far as getting everything setup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7

Comment: Anything you install with yum can be removed with `yum remove`

Comment: yum usually needs the whole package name

Answer (score 1):

I see the OP has already reinstalled mysql but I'd like to mention on CentOS you can use a great command which secures your installation for production and sets the mysql root password in the process. The command is: mysql_secure_installation
Here's how it works

first install mysql using yum

```
[root@mail ~]# yum install mysql-server
```

then set mysql to run at start up and start mysql

```
[root@mail ~]# chkconfig mysqld on
[root@mail ~]# service mysqld start
```

then run mysql secure installation here is sample output:
(when first run the mysql root password is blank so just hit enter for the first question)

```
[root@mail ~]# mysql_secure_installation
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
OK, successfully used password, moving on...
Set root password? [Y/n] y
New password:
Re-enter new password:
Password updated successfully!
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
... Success!
Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] n
... skipping.
Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
- Dropping test database...
... Success!
- Removing privileges on test database...
... Success!
Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
... Success!
Cleaning up...
All done!  If you've completed all of the above steps, your MySQL
installation should now be secure.
Thanks for using MySQL!
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to answer.  I have another posting.  Are you willing to help me with it also?  here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138568/editing-tomcat-users-xml-in-centos-7-linux

Comment: I'll try check out my answer, let me know if you can't get it because vi can be tricky

Answer (score 0):

With mysql you can:

1) connect you to mysql

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

2) run mysql command:

```
use mysql
```

3) run mysql command:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('NEWPASSWORD') where user='root';
```

4) run mysql command:

```
flush privileges;
```

​5) run mysql command:

```
quit
```

6) Now you can connect without password with

```
mysql -u root
```