# Editing tomcat-users.xml in CentOS 7 Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, terminal, centos, vi

I am trying to edit `tomcat-users.xml` in Tomcat 8, using the terminal of CentOS 7 Linux.  I typed `su -`  to use the terminal as the `root` account.

I then typed in `vi $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml`, but the result is that `vi` opens in the window with the contents of `tomcat-users.xml` in read-only mode, and there seems to be no way out of `vi` except to close the window, losing all the terminal history.

I also navigated to the physical location of `tomcat-users.xml` and opened up the file using Gedit, but Gedit will not allow me to save the file. How can I edit `tomcat-users.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open vi, you are in command mode. Type i to place yourself in insert mode. make your edits then when you are finished use the escape key to toggle back to command mode. Then type :q! to exit without saving or ZZ to save and close. I believe barjomet is correct that as root, :wq! will allow you to write to a read only file.

you might want to investigate why the file permissions are read only. See who owns the file and what the permissions are by using the ls command with the -l option
Example:
ls -l /some/folder/somefile.xml

change the permissions (if you know what you're doing) by using chmod command and change owner by using the chown command (be careful, don't mess up the permissions and create a security flaw, I can't help with that as I don't know tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit read-only file as root with vi — just type `:wq!` when you finish.

If you not familiar with vi and have vim installed — I recommend you to run `vimtutor` and spent about an hour to learn basics, otherwise read [this short tutorial](http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html).

Comment: The vi window that opens up does not allow me to type in it.  What syntax do i use to open up vi with editing enabled?  Like complete syntax for the line of code that opens up vi with the file name.  Thank you.

Comment: @barjomet `vi` is a text editor and `:wq!` indicates that you are willing to write to file and want to close the file. there is no relation with root or other users.

Comment: @CodeMed can you please share the full file description using following command? `ls -ltrh $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

Answer (score 0):

First thing to edit tomcat-user.xml file you need administrative privilege. If you the admin access. you can use vi or vim to edit the file
when the file opens, to edit the hit key *a or i*, it will let you edit at the bottom you can see Insert text. After editing to save press *esc* key can type :*wq!*